# PHP - Email with arabic characters

Tags: php, email, encoding

I'm building a small app to send my "2do" list stuff to Evernote over email. For the body of the message the characters are shown correctly but for the subject the characters are messed up. This is the PHP code:

The main PHP:

```
$subject      = $_POST["thesubject"];

    $bound_text=md5(uniqid(time()));
    $headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-$bound_text\"\r\n";

    $message="--PHP-mixed-$bound_text\r\n"      
                ."Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n"
                ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"  
                ."<html><head></head><body>"
                ."<div style=\"font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 1.3em; color: #000000;width: 100%;text-align: left;\">$text_message</div></body></html>\r\n\r\n"  
                ."--PHP-mixed-$bound_text\r\n"  
                ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
                ."Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$attachment\"\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=\"$attachment\"\r\n\r\n"
     .chunk_split($file)
            ."\r\n\r\n"
                ."--PHP-mixed-$bound_text--\r\n\r\n";

    }

The mail part:

    $subject_evernote = utf8_decode($subject); 
    mail($evernote,$subject_evernote,$message,$headers);
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Just get [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) and be happy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$subject_evernote = mb_encode_mimeheader("العربية");
```

Answer (score 3):

Email headers, which includes the subject, can only contain ASCII characters. Therefore you will have to MIME encode your non-ASCII characters so they conform to that requirement. Have a look at [`mb_encode_mimeheader`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-mimeheader.php).